# CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I have a very odd issue... in every browser and mobile version I encountered this behavior:

- all the browsers have a top menu when you load the page (showing the address bar for example) which slide up when you start scrolling the page.
- 100vh *sometimes* is calculated only on the visible part of a viewport, so when the browser bar slide up 100vh increases (in terms of pixels)
- all layout re-paint and re-adjust since the dimensions have changed
- a bad jumpy effect for user experience

How can avoid this problem? When I first heard of viewport-height I was excited and I thought I could use it for fixed height blocks instead of using javascript, but now I think the only way to do that is in fact javascript with some resize event...

you can see the problem at: [sample site](http://alphafitness.altervista.org/log.php)

Can anyone help me with / suggest a CSS solution?

---

simple test code:

```js
/* maybe i can track the issue whe it occours... */
$(function(){
  var resized = -1;
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#currenth').val( $('.vhbox').eq(1).height() );
    if (++resized) $('#currenth').css('background:#00c');
  })
  .resize();
})
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

/*
  this is the box which should keep constant the height...
  min-height to allow content to be taller than viewport if too much text
*/
.vhbox{
  min-height:100vh;
  position:relative;
}

.vhbox .t{
  display:table;
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}

.vhbox .c{
  height:100%;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="vhbox" style="background-color:#c00">
  <div class="t"><div class="c">
  this div height should be 100% of viewport and keep this height when scrolling page
    <br>
    <!-- this input highlight if resize event is fired -->
    <input type="text" id="currenth">
  </div></div>
</div>

<div class="vhbox" style="background-color:#0c0">
  <div class="t"><div class="c">
  this div height should be 100% of viewport and keep this height when scrolling page
  </div></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if i understood the question well the problem you are facing is in mobile browser the height is more than visible viewport hight..right?

Comment: Interesting, never noticed that before. Its mainly the background picture that is noticeably jumpy. How about you add a `transition: 0.5s` or so, to make the change less abruptly?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal nope, exatly the opposite: the real viewport height is greater than the one provided by the browser when its address bar is visible...

Comment: Since my question is becoming popular, I would like to give my 5 cents: wouldn't be more intelligent to mantain the real window height and only slide up the menu bar? it doesn't seems so difficult. In fact should be easier... finger up -> menu bar slide up until invisible, finger down -> menu bar slide down until completely visible... all altogether with the body without any re-adjusting and jumpy effect...

Comment: Google has some good info on this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing
You can use 100% instead of 100vh IF you have changed body height to 100%

Comment: I have noticed the opposite. Unfortunately `100vh` in Chrome on iOS equals `outerWidth` ***instead*** of `innerWidth`, which is causing me problems since those browsers bars only disappear when you scroll the `body` element. Unfortunately it is a child element that is being scrolled on my website, so the bars never disappear, and my website navigation is obscured by those browser bars...

Comment: @Benisburgers that completely breaks my layout. im hiding the scrollbars on an element with overflow, so that instead of scrolling the entire window, youre only scrolling the element with overflow

Comment: I think I came up with a really good solution to this "feature": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886797/how-to-access-a-the-real-100vh-on-ios-as-a-css-var

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74940497/background-image-is-over-zoomed-and-not-clearly-visible-in-iphone-browser/74948435#74948435 Here is the detailed explanation how I solved it.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

**Unfortunately this is intentional…**

This is a well know issue (at least in safari mobile), which is intentional, as it prevents other problems. [Benjamin Poulain replied to a webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832):

> This is completely intentional. It took quite a bit of work on our part to achieve this effect. :)
>
> The base problem is this: the visible area changes dynamically as you scroll. If we update the CSS viewport height accordingly, we need to update the layout during the scroll. Not only that looks like shit, but doing that at 60 FPS is practically impossible in most pages (60 FPS is the baseline framerate on iOS).
>
> It is hard to show you the “looks like shit” part, but imagine as you scroll, the contents moves and what you want on screen is continuously shifting.
>
> Dynamically updating the height was not working, we had a few choices: drop viewport units on iOS, match the document size like before iOS 8, use the small view size, use the large view size.
>
> From the data we had, using the larger view size was the best compromise. Most website using viewport units were looking great most of the time.

Nicolas Hoizey has researched this quite a bit: https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html

**No fix planned**

At this point, there is not much you can do except refrain from using viewport height on mobile devices. Chrome changed to this as well in 2016:

- https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/BK0oHURgmJ4
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing

Comment: can you provide an example with percentage units which works as the code snippet I wrote (`min-height: 100vh`)? Thank you for the answer... even if not bringing happy conclusion :)

Comment: After looking at your code in more detail, I can't see a way to work around this with percentage units, I'm sorry.

Comment: Yep, as I think. Only viable solution is a scripted solution. From what I know, `$(window).height()` is not affected by this bug, so I'll go that way. thank you!

Comment: The issue just maybe be that any content you have on your website with set widths that overflow the width of the device would mess up the how the page looks. My problem was just I had to set flex-wrap: wrap on the container containing the fixed-width items and 100vh worked just fine on all devices and all orientations...

Comment: Since Chrome version 56 the vh is always calculated as if the URL bar is hidden and therefore vh does not increase on scroll, except for `position:fixed`. This is similar to the implementation on Safari.  Read more: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing

Comment: Latest Chrome does not change `vh` or `<html> 100%` height after initial load. This is actually great - as layout thrashing/reflow when URL Bar hides can look dreadful. `Firefox` and `Edge` `Mobile` still dynamically update `vh` and `<html>` height, causing lots of tearing and resizing of all components when scrolling, especially bad if using SVGs for background images

Comment: Let me rephrase that: “we broke our browser, but it was so much work that we are going to keep it”... Is it just me, or does apple more and more become what Microsoft was 10 years ago?

Comment: yes, safari is the new IE. and chrome mimics it. anyways, behaviour on chrome today (june18) seems somewhat random: sometimes, it keeps the lower value, without addressbar, sometimes it updates...bullshit, really, is it.

Comment: Fixing the vh and 100% sizes was a great idea by iOS Safari and Chrome. Firefox vh and ICB (100% height) are recalculated every time URL Bar hides/appears, and it destroys scroll performance

Comment: I'm confused about this accepted answer. The question I (and the OP) seem to have is "why does the value of 100vh get recalculated as I scroll and cause a repaint?" The accepted answer seems to say: "This is intentional, quote: If we update the CSS viewport height accordingly, we need to update the layout during the scroll. Not only that looks like shit, but doing that at 60 FPS is practically impossible in most pages" which is exactly the behaviour we're seeing and want to fix. The quote is from a bug report saying webkit WON'T recalculate 100vh, but iOS Chrome DOES (and it looks like shit).

Comment: For anyone who's still following with this in 2019, the issue still persists. I'll summarise the latest situation as given in [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing) post - 

**Using `vh` will size the element as if the URL bar is always hidden while using % will size the element as if the URL bar were always showing.**

Though there's no "perfect" solution for this, the only workaround I can suggest is to use 100% for the 1st section of your page where the URL bar is usually showing when user opens it and use 100vh for all other sections.

Comment: There's a PostCSS plugin that fixes it: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-100vh-fix

Comment: Just in case it hasn't been mentioned yet: 100vh also behaves differently depending on if the WKWebView is running with the device connected to Xcode or not (!)

Comment: You can also check this article: [You Shouldn’t Rely on CSS 100vh and Here’s Why!](https://ilxanlar.medium.com/you-shouldnt-rely-on-css-100vh-and-here-s-why-1b4721e74487)

Comment: Hello! It's 2022. The 'bug' is still there. 100vh is including the Safari interface elements and does not give a reliable value. It seems like the best option is to have `:root { --app-height: 100vh; }` and let javascript overwrite that value with the `window.innerHeight` value. All calculations can then be made from a reliable var(--app-height) value. I don't know why they made something so vital so hard.

Comment: These web-kit engineers at apple are a joke. Pathetic.

Comment: For those here in the future, see @m4no's answer with the new dvh (etc) units - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245072/10909080

Answer (score 242):

You can try `min-height: -webkit-fill-available;` in your css instead of `100vh`. It should be solved

Comment: I would leave `min-height: 100vh;` in as a fallback where `-webkit-fill-available` isn't supported.

Comment: @TammyTee is right, it's better to keep ```min-height: 100vh;``` in there as it will otherwise break on browsers like Firefox (at least on desktop, iOS uses webkit no matter what browser).

Comment: This introduces issues with the keyboard on Android Chrome. It seems to keep its smaller height after the keyboard is hidden.

Comment: This was a very nice solution, but seems to have changed in iOS 13 — I'm seeing extra space at the bottom of the first section, but it works exactly as desired in Safari for iOS 12.x https://codepen.io/RwwL/pen/PowjvPq (you'd have to fork this then view it in CodePen debug mode on iOS to really see what I mean).

Comment: Thanks this is so clean! btw I ended using this version, since my app relies on height to be non-zero at first `height: 100vh;  max-height: -webkit-fill-available;`

Comment: Since Chrome v84, -webkit-fill-available is no longer supported. :/

Comment: While this approach is by far the easiest of them all -- it does have some issues with not recalculating when i.e. the mobile keyboard pops up.

Comment: This is awesome. I'm pretty sure order matters here. We're pretty used to doing things like this: `-webkit-bleedingedgethingy: 1; bleedingedgethingy: 1;` so when the regular version makes it into the spec, that takes precedence. But here you want the vendor specific one to override the normal setting so `height: 100vh;  height: -webkit-fill-available;` not the other way around.

Comment: It is interesting how it also accounts for the border size and subtracts it. Very useful.

Comment: just as a possibility with Bootstrap4, html style "height: 100vh" and class "vh-100" to body seem to work

Comment: @JoeSeifi answer has helped me. my issue was horizontally centered div was causing scroll on mobile and wasn't centered correctly. height: 100vh but adding max-height: -webkit-fill-available; took care of everything.

Comment: Can you use `calc` on this like you can with `vh` units?

Comment: Solution doesn't do anything

Answer (score 226):

We have new viewport units `lvh`, `svh` and `dvh` to the rescue. This was demonstrated in the latest Google I/O 2022 video on web works.

You would probably want to stick with `dvh` for the browser to adapt to the mobile device's hidden tabs while scrolling. It works the similar way for width with `dvw`, `lvw` and `svw` units.

Here is a neat illustration from the video: https://youtu.be/Xy9ZXRRgpLk?t=982

[image: Google I/O 2022 on new viewport units]

[Can I use?](https://caniuse.com/?search=dvh)

This was currently working on my Chrome canary with the flag "Experimental features" enabled.

Comment: Any idea when this will be released in a stable Chrome release?

Comment: @ViBoNaCci You can check the updates here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1093055

Comment: It's going to release in Chrome 108: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/Qw2XTr0et_U?pli=1 https://nimb.ws/q6mfaI

Comment: December 2022 we can finally use dvh with confidence.

Comment: Note that this does lead to some jank. on iOS 16.3, even though the dynamic viewport height changes smoothly, elements with `100dvh` absolutely do not; they only update their height when the animation finishes.

Comment: As of Feb 2023 you should still use a fallback (e.g. height: 100vh; height: 100dvh;) - https://caniuse.com/viewport-unit-variants

Comment: I love this! `svh` looks perfect for a header/intro block that should take up the entire screen. It will prevent the yanks @BallpointBen mentions. `dvh` seems perfect for the background of modal popups.

Comment: I can't believe it but is this true? It's May 2023, I just tested and it WORKS like a charm: `100svh` is what we all have been waiting for.

Comment: This should really be top answer

Works so well on all major mobile browsers

Comment: Yes, this should be the accepted answer as it's working on almost all mobile browsers!

Comment: As it was stated in the post caniuse, `svh` is still not widely supported, if you are planing to make your site compatible as much as possible in most of old browsers, i would suggest to not use this.

Comment: Yes, but I would not suggest developing for older browsers.

Answer (score 89):

update **2023**: please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245072/4773272 which is the better way nowadays.

---

Legacy answer:
in my app I do it like so (typescript and nested postcss, so change the code accordingly):

```js
const appHeight = () => {
    const doc = document.documentElement
    doc.style.setProperty('--app-height', `${window.innerHeight}px`)
}
window.addEventListener('resize', appHeight)
appHeight()
```

in your css:

```css
:root {
    --app-height: 100%;
}

html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    @media not all and (hover:hover) {
        height: var(--app-height);
    }
}
```

it works at least on chrome mobile and ipad. What doesn't work is when you add your app to homescreen on iOS and change the orientation a few times - somehow the zoom levels mess with the innerHeight value, I might post an update if I find a solution to it.

[Demo](https://mendrik.github.io/preact-easy-state/)

Comment: I would like to add a warning that "@media not all and (hover:hover) {" is not a bulletproof way to detect mobile browsers. Feel free to use something else.

Comment: I like this approach a lot.  One comment I would make is on the use of the event listener.  This causes a re-paint of the page and I only use it in certain scenarios when it is absolutely critical for the user to see the correct viewport (i.e. the home page initial view)

Comment: @AndreasHerd is this sass, not css? I'm not familiar with nesting the media query inside the body selector area

Comment: @asyncawait I used postcss in this case, but most css post-processors support nested css. You can easily flatten it out into regular css, though.

Comment: I wanted to give a small update: please check out dynamic units in css instead. height: 100dvh is probably doing the magic nowadays.

Answer (score 52):

For me such trick made a job:

```css
height: calc(100vh - calc(100vh - 100%))
```

Comment: Is it different than height: 100% ?

Comment: Yes, 100vh is 100% of a viewport height (your device), when pure 100% only fill all available parent area (parent block can have e.g. 50px height and it will fill only to this parent height). In big short.

Comment: This simple trick did work indeed, although the address bar doesn't hide, but it's better then the other solutions. upvote from me.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!
This is by far the cleanest solution. Tested in Firefox (desktop and mobile), Chrome (desktop and mobile) and Safari (mobile)

Comment: This actually the same as write `height: 100%` because it translates to `100vh - 100vh + 100%`. So this approach can be called "don't use vh at all".

Important note: in order to be able to use `height: 100%`, you must propagate that height from the root element through all the children till the target element. Sometimes it may be too difficult

Comment: What @SleepWalker said is correct, The result is exactly the same as Hight: 100%.

Comment: Setting the `height: 100%` worked for me. The element had **display** property set to **fixed**, I can't tell if this solution would work for absolute display (`display: absolute`)

Comment: Here are a few links to why it is not the same:
- https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/
- https://nicolas-hoizey.com/articles/2015/02/18/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers/
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832
Long story short. The math says these approaches are the same, and in most cases that is true. Still, they are differently implemented by different browsers and versions, which is why this can sometimes help.

Answer (score 48):

Look at this answer: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

```js
// First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
// Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);

// We listen to the resize event
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // We execute the same script as before
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

.module {
  height: 100vh; /* Use vh as a fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 30%;
}

.module__item {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.module__item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #F73859;
}

.module__item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F73859;
  color: #F1D08A;
}
```

```html
<div class="module">
  <div class="module__item">20%</div>
  <div class="module__item">40%</div>
  <div class="module__item">60%</div>
  <div class="module__item">80%</div>
  <div class="module__item">100%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: very nice solution. Just in my case, I didn't use ponyfill, but rather logic that for all desktop sites I use 100vh, while for mobile I use var (we don't have IE11 in mobile world).

Comment: Only solution that worked for nested elements. In anyone else has to replace a couple hundred instances, you can (at least most of the time) match the regexp (-)?([\d.]+)vh and replace it with calc(var(--vh) * $1$2)

Comment: However, there is a warning: Updating the value of --vh will trigger a repaint of the page and the user may experience a jump as a result.

Comment: there are multiplication losses on * 0.01. I have about 20px. better to have --100vh variable which will be set from `let full_vh = window.innerHeight - 1;`

Answer (score 40):

Set your body position to fixed, set the height to 100%

```
body { position: fixed; height: 100% }
```

That's it, then the mobile browser will understand what you want.

Now the body will grow or shrink following the browser's view height, no matter if there is a URL bar or not, or if there are tabs (like in mobile safari) or not. The body will always get full view.

Comment: This actually ended up working for me.  Instead of the body element body, I used the above styles on my <main> element which is a direct child of body and it solved it for Safari, Chrome, and DuckDuckGo on mobile. I'm not sure if it's considered "best practice" or not but ill make sure to comment if I find anything that breaks as I build out the site more.

Comment: Thanks, it was also a solution for me that works well!

Comment: magically works for me. Not sure if this is safe to use. But using it anyway. Will update if something breaks.

Comment: This forces the browser toolbar to stay open. If you're ok with that, then this is great. I needed to use `overscroll-behavior: none` along with this for it to work well. But then it indeed does work well.

Answer (score 31):

You can do this by adding following script and style

```js
function appHeight() {
  const doc = document.documentElement
  doc.style.setProperty('--vh', (window.innerHeight*.01) + 'px');
}

window.addEventListener('resize', appHeight);
appHeight();
```

Style

```css
.module {
  height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
  height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}
```

Comment: This is fully described here: https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/#css-custom-properties-the-trick-to-correct-sizing

Comment: This doesn't work on iPhone XR Chrome, the bottom nav bar is still covering up 100vh element

Answer (score 26):

For many of the sites I build the client will ask for a 100vh banner and just as you have found, it results in a bad "jumpy" experience on mobile when you begin to scroll. This is how I solve the problem for a smooth consistent experience across all devices:

I first set my banner element CSS to `height:100vh`

Then I use jQuery to get the height in pixels of my banner element and apply an inline style using this height.

```
var viewportHeight = $('.banner').outerHeight();
$('.banner').css({ height: viewportHeight });
```

Doing this solves the issue on mobile devices as when the page loads, the banner element is set to 100vh using CSS and then jQuery overrides this by putting inline CSS on my banner element which stops it from resizing when a user begins to scroll.

However, on desktop if a user resizes their browser window my banner element won't resize because it now has a fixed height set in pixels due to the above jQuery. To address this I use [Mobile Detect](http://mobiledetect.net/) to add a 'mobile' class to the body of my document. And then I wrap the above jQuery in an if statement:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('mobile')) {
  var viewportHeight = $('.banner').outerHeight();
  $('.banner').css({ height: viewportHeight });
}
```

As a result, if a user is on a mobile device the class 'mobile' is present on the body of my page and the above jQuery is executed. So my banner element will only get the inline CSS applied on mobile devices meanwhile on desktop the original 100vh CSS rule remains in place.

Comment: I would tweak it to use `$('.banner').css({ height: window.innerHeight });` instead, which is the "real" height of the viewport.  [Example of how innerHeight works](https://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/KmJmVm)

Comment: Which is `document.querySelector('.banner').style.height = window.innerHeight;` for people writing actual JavaScript.

Answer (score 21):

I came up with a React component – [check it out](http://npmjs.com/package/react-div-100vh) if you use React or [browse the source code](https://github.com/mvasin/react-div-100vh) if you don't, so you can adapt it to your environment.

It sets the fullscreen `div`'s height to `window.innerHeight` and then updates it on window resizes.

Comment: And for Vue lovers ... https://github.com/razumnyak/vue-div-100vh

Answer (score 10):

As I was looking for a solution some days, here is mine for everyone using VueJS with Vuetify (my solution uses v-app-bar, v-navigation-drawer and v-footer):
I created App.scss (used in App.vue) with the following content:

```css
.v-application {
    height: 100vh;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.v-application--wrap {
    min-height: 100vh !important;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available !important;
}
```

Comment: This seemed to work at first for me, but then I noticed that it doesn't resize the container on orientation change on mobile devices.

Comment: ```html {
height: 100vh;
height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

body,
body > div,
.v-application,
.v-application--wrap {
 height: 100vh;
 height: -webkit-fill-available;
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Saved both problems for me. Finally

Answer (score 7):

You can try giving `position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0;` properties to your container.

Comment: Add more info on why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: I find this very effective in my case, using a flex layout to show a small vertically centered box which can scroll when it grows in height

Comment: This is a great answer. I used `inset: 0` instead of top and bottom. By placing position fixed and inset 0 onto the html, the body will scroll when its height hits the limit of the html. This allows for the disappearing address bar to be locked in place.

Answer (score 5):

The the problem still remains to this date, unfortunately. And the biggest misleading it's impossible to represent the situation by using browser's [`devices toolbar`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/).

I've just solved the issue like so (tested on PC, iOS and android browsers):

```css
.your_class {
   height: 100vh,
   max-height: 100%, // <-- add the line
   ...some other props,
}
```

I hope it'll save your time.

Comment: I was using '100vh' but I realized that the content would clip at the bottom because the the content was still 100vh but the browser bar would push the content down. Height: 100% for me was the correct approach.

Comment: I agree with the last comment, having the two heights gives a correct measurement, also it is widely compatible, unless lvh, svh & dvh.

Answer (score 4):

@nils explained it clearly.

What's next then?

I just went back to use relative 'classic' **`%` (percentage)** in CSS.

It's often more effort to implement something than it would be using `vh`, but at least, you have a pretty stable solution which works across different devices and browsers without strange UI glitches.

Comment: The height: 100% for banners still jumps on mobile browsers. I've been testing it on Android, and so far Chrome and Opera Mini gives 100% as the visible VP height, and does not change on scroll. Edge and Firefox change the 100% height, and repaint the view. Firefox is especially bad, with tearing, text rerendered, very obviously re-layout

Answer (score 3):

The following code solved the problem (with jQuery).

```
var vhHeight = $("body").height();
var chromeNavbarHeight = vhHeight - window.innerHeight;
$('body').css({ height: window.innerHeight, marginTop: chromeNavbarHeight });
```

And the other elements use `%` as a unit to replace `vh`.

Answer (score 3):

I have created two examples below:

1. To showcase how `height: 100vh` as height can lead to scroll in mobile chrome browsers:

**code** : https://codesandbox.io/embed/mobile-viewport-100vh-issue-nxx8z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

**demo**: https://nxx8z.csb.app/

---

2. Solution using `position: fixed` to resolve the issue and with purely CSS:

**code** : https://codesandbox.io/s/mobile-viewport-100vh-issue-fix-forked-ypx5x?file=/index.html

**demo** : https://ypx5x.csb.app/

Comment: Amazing, simple and accurate solution, thanks :+1

Answer (score 2):

I just found a web app i designed has this issue with iPhones and iPads, and found an article suggesting to solve it using media queries targeted at specific Apple devices.

I don't know whether I can share the code from that article here, but the address is this: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-fix-for-ios-vh-unit-bug

Quoting the article: "just match the element height with the device height using media queries that targets the older versions of iPhone and iPad resolution."

They added just 6 media queries to adapt full height elements, and it should work as it is fully CSS implemented.

Edit pending: I'm unable to test it right now, but I will come back and report my results.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not came back as promised. But after fiddling with the HTML and the CSS for much longer than I would have liked, I changed the design of my layout and found a way that worked "ok" for my needs, but was not a universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

As I am new, I can't comment on other answers.

If someone is looking for an answer to make this work (and can use javascript - as it seems to be required to make this work at the moment) this approach has worked pretty well for me and it accounts for mobile orientation change as well. I use Jquery for the example code but should be doable with vanillaJS.

-First, I use a script to detect if the device is touch or hover. Bare-bones example:

```
if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) {
    document.body.classList.add('touch-device');

} else {
    document.body.classList.add('hover-device');
}
```

This adds class to the body element according to the device type (hover or touch) that can be used later for the height script.

-Next use this code to set height of the device on load and on orientation change:

```
if (jQuery('body').hasClass("touch-device")) {
//Loading height on touch-device
    function calcFullHeight() {
        jQuery('.hero-section').css("height", $(window).height());
    }

    (function($) {
        calcFullHeight();

        jQuery(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
            // 500ms timeout for getting the correct height after orientation change
            setTimeout(function() {
                calcFullHeight();
            }, 500);

        });
    })(jQuery);

} else {
    jQuery('.hero-section').css("height", "100vh");


}
```

-Timeout is set so that the device would calculate the new height correctly on orientation change. If there is no timeout, in my experience the height will not be correct. 500ms might be an overdo but has worked for me.

-100vh on hover-devices is a fallback if the browser overrides the CSS 100vh.

Comment: Touchstart is not supported on all browsers, and some non-mobile devices have it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart

Comment: @Drenai Touchstart is supported on most mobile browsers. On desktop the support is a little less, IE, Opera and Safari are not supporting it. However the original question is aimed at mobile and not desktop. Which makes this a valid answer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have mainly used this tactics to overcome readjusting and jumpiness of the screen on some mobile browsers. If the browser doesn't support touchstart the fallback will be the css 100vh - if 100vh is not supported that's a different topic. If the desktop device happens to have touch support then the height will be calculated with javascript. We then lose the re-calculation on resize that 100vh provides, but it's not a fatal issue in general as there aren't orientation changes on desktop.

Comment: Also, the height calculation could also be attached to resize event but then we can run into the same exact problem of readjusting and jumpiness on mobile devices. Therefore, I have found this tactics to be practical.

Comment: @Drenai could you give an example of a better way to detect mobile browsers? Sure, screen size could be used but there are bigger tablets than laptops out there so I haven't find that perfect either.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use recommended approaches such as `-webkit-fill-available`.
I just spent all day rushing around to fix this "bug".

Add a class when your app is loaded with a browser with a "chin".

JavaScript

```
// Angular example but applicable for any JS solution
@HostBinding('class.browser-has-chin') browserHasChin: boolean = false;

public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.browserHasChin = this._isMobileSafari();
}

private _isMobileSafari() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/AppleWebKit/) ? true : false;
}
```

CSS

```
.browser-has-chin {
  @media screen and (max-device-width: 767px){
    // offset with padding or something
  }
}
```

**NOTES:**
There are major issues with the `-webkit-fill-available` prop for cross-browser compatibility.

I was able to get it working in Chrome and iOS Safari to fix the chin/height calculation issue. However it broke Android Chrome and Firefox had bugs with it too.

It seems that `-webkit-fill-available` was rushed into webkit at some point and perhaps adopted haphazardly by Apple as a fix for chin/height calculation?

It relies on [intrinsic sizing](https://caniuse.com/intrinsic-width) which is NOT safe to use yet.

Answer (score 2):

React hooks solution with useEffect and useState

```js
    function App() {
      const [vh, setVh] = useState(window.innerHeight);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const updateVh = () => {
          setVh(window.innerHeight);
        };
    
        window.addEventListener('resize', updateVh);
    
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateVh);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div style={{ height: vh }}>
          {vh} px
        </div>
      );
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/poooow/k570nfd9/

Comment: Great solution! With a little tweaking, this is working well in Next.JS too.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
html { height: 100vh; }

body {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

/* this is the container you want to take the visible viewport  */
/* make sure this is top-level in body */
#your-app-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The `body` will take the visible viewport height and `#your-app-container` with `height: 100%` will make that container take the visible viewport height.

Answer (score 1):

The VH 100 does not work well on mobile as it does not factor in the iOS bar (or similar functionality on other platforms).

One solution that works well is to use JavaScript "window.innerHeight".

Simply assign the height of the element to this value e.g.
$('.element-name').height(window.innerHeight);

Note: It may be useful to create a function in JS, so that the height can change when the screen is resized. However, I would suggest only calling the function when the width of the screen is changed, this way the element will not jump in height when the iOS bar disappears when the user scrolls down the page.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
}
```

100% will adjust it self to the screen size but for some reason
100vh have a problem on adjusting when the screen changes so using the bottom 0 will be affected thus if you use 100vh or 100%

###### for  example when the search bar is in view or not in mobile the 100% with change where as 100vh will stick on the first value of the screens height

Answer (score 0):

Because [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113430/6734406) won't be fixed, you can do something like:

```
# html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <!-- Your stuff here -->
  </div>
</body>

# css
.content {
  height: 80vh;
}
```

For me it was the fastest and more pure solution than playing with the JavaScript which could not work on many devices and browsers.

Just use proper value of `vh` which fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using vh on mobile devices is not going to work with 100vh, due to their design choices using the entire height of the device not including any address bars etc.

If you are looking for a layout including div heights proportionate to the true view height I use the following pure css solution:

```
:root {
  --devHeight: 86vh; //*This value changes
}

.div{
    height: calc(var(--devHeight)*0.10); //change multiplier to suit required height
}
```

You have two options for setting the viewport height, manually set the --devHeight to a height that works (but you will need to enter this value for each type of device you are coding for)

or

Use javascript to get the window height and then update --devheight on loading and refreshing the viewport (however this does require using javascript and is not a pure css solution)

Once you obtain your correct view height you can create multiple divs at an exact percentage of total viewport height by simply changing the multiplier in each div you assign the height to.

0.10 = 10% of view height
0.57 = 57% of view height

Hope this might help someone ;)

Comment: That's a nice solution. You can read more about this on **[this article on Css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a work around I used for my React app.

iPhone 11 Pro & iPhone Pro Max - 120px

iPhone 8 - 80px

```
max-height: calc(100vh - 120px);
```

It's a compromise but relatively simple fix

Comment: Having a hard coded value will cause unseen errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A nice read about the problem and its possible solutions can be found in this blog post: [Addressing the iOS Address Bar in 100vh Layouts](https://medium.com/@susiekim9/how-to-compensate-for-the-ios-viewport-unit-bug-46e78d54af0d)

The solution I ended up in my React application is utilising the [react-div-100vh](https://github.com/mvasin/react-div-100vh) library described in the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Brave browser on iOS behaves differently (buggy?). It changes viewport height dynamically accordingly to showing/hiding address bar. It is kind of annoying because it changes page's layout dependent on vw/vh units.

Chrome and Safari is fine.

Comment: i think brave is the only browser that works correctly - the screen updates as the navbars dynamically hide - something apple admits was too much work for safari

Comment: Well, it definitely looks odd on my website, because image width is dependent on its height which is dynamically changing because of those navbars. I would prefer Chrome/Safari behaviour for my site.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by putting the most outer div at `position: absolute` and then just setting the `height` to `100%`:

CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="outer">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like CSS fix is unreliable and JS one works fine but the element is jumping when user opens the page.

I solved the issue using `JS from other answers + fadeIn animation` to hide jumping.

This won't fit all the use cases, but for some of them, like a button that has to be at the bottom, could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Android Chrome and Opera

`height: calc(100% - 1px);`

I.e deduction at least a pixel will do the job
I also set the body, html height to 100%

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and am now using `100dvh` instead of `100vh`. In addition to this, I have also applied this CSS to my body div

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `html, body { height: 100% }` for something to the effect of 100vh on mobile devices.

Comment: Setting the `height: 100%` on the target element worked for me. The element had **display** property set to **fixed**, I can't tell if this solution would work for absolute display (`display: absolute`) on the target element or setting the **height** property of both **html** and **body** to **100%**

Answer (score -1):

In my case it - I had some element set to 90vh and another element set to 70px
Changed the 70px to 10vh solved it

> Never mix vh with px units

Answer (score -1):

The people who found this answer and are struggling with an issue of wiered jumping of elements on mobile view when scrolling downward/upward whose position is fixed w.r.t the root element need to specify the property in terms of bottom rather than top and should give a field value in px. This solves the issue

change this:

```css
element{
position: fixed;
top: 90vh;
left: 90vh;
transform: translate(-95%, -95%);


}
```

to this:

```css
    element{
    position: fixed;
   bottom: 90px; /* this is the change */
    left: 90vh;
    transform: translate(-95%, -95%);


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

problem :

```
if ( refDOM.clientHeight != window.innerHeight )
```

Solution :

```
refDOM.style.setProperty('--MYvh', window.innerHeight + 'px' ) ;
```

---

complete :

```
const mobileShit = function ( refDOM ) {
    console.log ( `refDOM.clientHeight : ${refDOM.clientHeight}` ) ;
    console.log ( `window.innerHeight : ${window.innerHeight}` ) ;
    if ( refDOM.clientHeight != window.innerHeight ) { // accounting for mobile
        refDOM.style.setProperty('--MYvh', window.innerHeight + 'px' ) ;
    }
} ;
```

---

CSS (modified by script, and yes, you have to handle events when anything changes) :

```
:root {
    --MYvh : 100vh ;
}
```

Comment:  mobileShit great name.

Answer (score -1):

Solved jumpy or hiding under URL or utility bar issues using CSS only.

I wanted to make a persistent player always floating 10px above bottom and implemented it with

```css
   #player {
     display: fixed;
     top: calc(100vh - var(--player-height) - 10px);
   }
```

It worked in desktop browsers. It was at correct position when URL bar was collapsed in mobile browsers, but was hiding under expanded URL bar.
On going through the solutions offered here like

```css
    top:calc(100% - var(--player-height) - 10px);
    top:calc(100dvh - var(--player-height) - 10px);
```

Both percentage % method and dynamic-viewport-height(dvh) technically worked, but were not smooth and were triggering only after scroll stops and mouseUp/leave touch events (my understanding) and causing delayed and abrupt shift of player.

I thought of working the javaScript way but found a solution in CSS only.

Instead of defining from top, I wrote from bottom and used % way

```css
    #player {
      display: fixed;
      bottom: 1%;
    }
```

It solved all jumping issues, is smooth and works even when collapsible bars at both top and bottom in some browsers(Edge). If pic or content needs to fit exact viewable area, instead of constraining from top and giving height, constrain container from top and bottom in pixels or percentages.