# How do I make CSS grid fill window height?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid

What is the best (simplest/most efficient) way to make a css grid fill the height of the window at any size without using `overflow: hidden` or something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: `height:100vh`?

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: I'll write an answer, so you can mark your question as answered.

Comment: vh and vw present problems with scrollbars and virtual keyboards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want to do, you could use *viewport units*. These are based on the viewport size (the size of your browser window).

> 1vh = 1% of the viewport height
>  
>     1vw = 1% of the viewport width

So, to scale an element as wide/high as the viewport, you could just use:
`100vh / 100vw`. In your case that would be `100vh`.

Comment: vh and vw present problems with scrollbars and virtual keyboards. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser