# Wordpress Twenty Seventeen Header Scroll Mobile Zooms in

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am using WordPress Twenty Seventeen for my website and I am having an issue with my header image on mobile. When I go to start scrolling, the header image kinda zooms-in, I have tried to google this issue but came up with nothing, I've tried going through the CSS code and don't see any transitions or the elements changing when I inspect them, Here is an example site:

https://2017.wordpress.net/

The header image is shorta zooms in when you start scrolling, is there away to prevent this so it stays the same size before scroll?

Comment: What kind of device are you seeing this behavior on?

Comment: iPhone and Android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because mobile-chrome calculates the address bar into the viewport height and while scrolling webpage the address bar scrolls too and the visible area changes it's height dynamically.

E.g. on `320px X 360px` screen, on mobile-chrome with address bar the height of viewport is `564px` and after scroll when address bar disappears, the height of viewport changes to `620px`.

---

**Viewport Height with address bar**

[image]

---

**Viewport Height without address bar**

[image]

---

Now `image` in `.wp-custom-header` taking `min-height:100%;height:100%` which will change height dynamically, therefore image changing it's dimension while scrolling.

Better way is to fix height of image in pixels in `media queries`.

```
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img{
    height: 620px;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Similar issue:

[css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 4):

Add `position: relative;` to your cover `img`:

```
.wp-custom-header img {
    position: relative;
}
```

The current position is `fixed`, which in conjunction with `object-fit: cover;`, is causing the zoom effect.

Comment: This works, however I still need the image to be in the fixed position so I can do the parallax image

Comment: @user979331, in that case just set the `relative` position for mobile, you will still have parallax on the desktop. Parallax feels wonky and slow on mobile anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following css:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

This will prevent the browsers from hiding address bar. So we will get rid of the jump while we scroll.

I have tried this in your url and it is working.
I suggest to use this in appropriate media queries.