# Sticky header on css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I've got a nifty responsive css template using css grids and I'd like to make the header of this responsive css grid sticky, but because of the way the header and nav is designed, I can't get it to use fixed positioning.

is there a better way of doing this with some grid property I might not have seen yet?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header,
nav {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

nav span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  display: none;
}

aside {
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  background: pink;
}


/* mobile  */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* tablets */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 275px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  nav {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
    height: 50px;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  main {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* desktops */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 10% 275px 1fr 10%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  header {
    display: block;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  nav {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  main {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
  }
}


/* xl desktops */

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 300px) minmax(auto, 1620px) 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<nav>
  <span>Logo</span>
  <a href="#">login</a>
</nav>
<aside>aside</aside>
<main>main</main>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/90kotz8d/3/

Comment: Using `position: fixed` will take it out of the flow, and thus won't be part of your grid system. To achieve this, you can use the non-standard [`position: sticky;`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) with `top: 0;`, the fallback being it behaving like a non-sticky element.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Sticky footer in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46158844/3597276)

Comment: def not a duplicate. @chriskirknielsen your solution solved it! would accept it if you post it as an answer. thanks

Comment: @totalnoob You got it. Added as an answer, glad to help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed header in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258653/fixed-header-in-css-grid)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

﻿Using `position: fixed;` will take it out of the flow, and thus won't be part of your grid system. To achieve this, you can use the non-standard `position: sticky;` with `top: 0;`, the fallback being it behaving like a non-sticky element.

Here, I'm assuming the `nav` element is your header, since your `header` is set to `display: none;` but the `position` property can be moved to any element of your grid (why put `header` in your markup if you're not going to show it?)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header,
nav {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
}

nav {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

nav span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  display: none;
}

aside {
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  background: pink;
}


/* mobile  */

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* tablets */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 275px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  nav {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
    height: 50px;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 1;
  }
  main {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  nav,
  aside,
  main {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}


/* desktops */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 10% 275px 1fr 10%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  header {
    display: block;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  nav {
    grid-column: 2 / 4;
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  aside {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
  }
  main {
    grid-column: 3 / 4;
  }
}


/* xl desktops */

@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  body {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(auto, 300px) minmax(auto, 1620px) 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<nav>
  <span>Logo</span>
  <a href="#">login</a>
</nav>
<aside>aside</aside>
<main>main</main>
```