# Vuejs: 100vh on mobile browsers

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have page with `min-height: 100vh` 
and it renders on mobile browsers with some overflow on bottom. And I use this script to fix it:

```
  methods: {
    calcVH() {
      const vH = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight, window.screen.height || 0)
      document.getElementById('app').style.height = vH + 'px';
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.calcVH();
    window.addEventListener('onorientationchange', this.calcVH, true);
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.calcVH, true);
  }
```

It works ok in emulator, but it doesn't work on chrome/safari mobile.
Did anyone have same problem?

Comment: What does it look like when it doesn't work?

Comment: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-fix-for-ios-vh-unit-bug

Comment: I think the proper event name is `orientationchange` (without the `on` prefix).

Comment: I think this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58886797/how-to-access-a-the-real-100vh-on-ios-as-a-css-var

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I had similar issues using `vh`. It's a [known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser).

My suggestion for you is to stop using `vh` on mobile and tablets in order to avoid these kind of hacks around. Use classic relative `%` (percentage) values instead. Since I've replaced `vh` with `%` I have no such problems on mobiles but it requires a bit more implementation effort. Using `%` isn't straightforward in all cases, but it pays you back since you've got a solution which works pretty everywhere in the same predictable way.

Answer (score 0):

This VueJS component is designed to solve it:

- https://github.com/razumnyak/vue-div-100vh

```js
<template>
  <vue100vh :css="{height: '100rvh';}">
    <marquee>Your stuff goes here</marquee>
  </vue100vh>
</template>

<script>
import vue100vh from 'vue-100vh'

export default {
  components: { vue100vh },
}
</script>
```

Works for smaller percentages ... where rvh = "real viewport height".

```js
<vue100vh :style="{ minHeight: '50rvh' }">
  <marquee>This is inside a div that takes at least 50% of viewport height.</marquee>
</vue100vh>
```