# Why 100vh makes a div taller than the visible area in Safari for iOS?

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

I'm designing a web page for mobile. This page has an overlay `div` with `height: 100vw;`.

On iOS it occupies a height that goes beyond the toolbars at 628px (see screenshot below), on the console however `window.innerHeight` returns a smaller value of 553px.

Why?

Also, how do I make it the size of the visible area through CSS?

[image]

Comment: It's probably due to the floating address bar on iOS Safari, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37112218/483779).