# How to create this effect on Image with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to design a login page for my website. I found one that I like a lot but I've been facing some problems when trying to implement it into mine.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
[Example](https://colorlib.com/etc/lf/Login_v1/index.html)

For example I'm using Bootstrap 3 for this:

```css
#particles-js{
    background: #dd4814;
    height: 100vh;
}

#login{
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 2em;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn-orange{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #dd4814;
    border-color: #dd4814;
}

.btn-orange:hover{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #ce4211;
}

.login-title{
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="particles-js">
    <div id="login">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank"><img vspace="50" class="img-responsive" src="https://codeigniter.com/assets/images/ci-logo-big.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form>
                    <span class="login-title">Member Login</span>
                    <!-- Username -->
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="no" required>
                    <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Password -->
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="no" required>
                        <span class="form-control-feedback"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-orange btn-block">Log In</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <a href="#">Forgot password</a> | <a href="#">Register</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
```

Not only that effect I'm having troubles with but with the background as well; the background goes all the way down when accessing via a computer or tablet but when accessing with a cell phone is not working as I want to.

I hope I could make myself clear.

> NOTE: the background issue is not really a concern, I just pointed it
>   out if somebody would like to help me out on that one but it is not
>   necessary. What I really want help with, is with the image effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like in the example they're using a library called [tilt.js](https://gijsroge.github.io/tilt.js/), so you could just use that to achieve the effect you're looking for.
If you were to code that by hand, I'd start by looking at the [tilt.js source code here](https://github.com/gijsroge/tilt.js/blob/master/src/tilt.jquery.js).

As for the background, I'm not sure what exactly the problem is, but since you are using `height: 100vh` and having problems on mobile, I assume the background is being to high? That'd be a known issue discussed in other questions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser).

Answer (score 1):

https://codepen.io/ariona/pen/JopOOr
see this example 
its posted on codepen you just need to search before post a question :)

css

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700);
body {
  background: #edf2f4;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
          perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Playfair Display",georgia,serif;
}

.card {
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
          transform: translateZ(0);
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  position: relative;
}
.card:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -50px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
          box-shadow: 0 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card .card-content {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.card h1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
          transform: translateZ(100px);
}
.card p {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(50px);
          transform: translateZ(50px);
  display: block;
}
.card p.related {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(80px);
          transform: translateZ(80px);
  font-style: italic;
}
.card a {
  color: #69c6b8;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

js jquery

```
var card = $(".card");

$(document).on("mousemove",function(e) {  
  var ax = -($(window).innerWidth()/2- e.pageX)/20;
  var ay = ($(window).innerHeight()/2- e.pageY)/10;
  card.attr("style", "transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg);-moz-transform: rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)");
});
```

html

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <h1>Just hover around</h1>
    <p><small>by <a href="http://ariona.net" target="_blank">Ariona, Rian</a></small></p>
    <p class="related"><strong>See also: </strong><a href="https://codepen.io/ariona/details/LVZLGP/" target="_blank">Staged dropdown animation</a></p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually tried but I just did not know how to search for it, I mean I did not even know that effect was called 3D hover plane effect. Thanks.