# Why min-height 100vh on iOS 10 results in large window?

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari

Can someone explain to me why when I set min-height of my section to calc(100vh), it results in a large window size and small text on iOS 10 (iPhone SE)?

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  min-height: calc(100vh);
  text-align: center;
}

section div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Description</h2>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must include the code needed to reproduce the problem in your question itself. It is not up to us to start debugging an entire website,  seeing that you do not mention which section you're talking about... Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we'll be happy to help :)

Comment: Check your meta viewport: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: Yes, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> helped. What's mobile safari's default behaviour when I'm not defining it?

Comment: Likely the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser from that this works `.full-heigth { min-height: 100vh; min-height: -webkit-fill-available}` for me

Answer (score 0):

have you make default body styling. `body{margin:0; padding:0}` if not please try this. It may solve your issue if you are using above html,css.