# Prevent extra scrolling on safari mobile when viewport is 100vh

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that if I have just a single div, with a height set to 100vh, there is always some vertical scrolling going on which sometimes messes up content on my page.

This is just on mobile safari. Is there a way where we can prevent that scrolling and have a feel more like mobile chrome or is it something that we have to live with?

Comment: have you tried adding `box-sizing:border-box;`?

Comment: see also https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser