# how can i make this be height: 100vh on mobile and or scrollable

Tags: css, sass, responsive

I am working on a small [Web-App](https://hamburg-attractions-guide.herokuapp.com). I want to make it responsive for smaller devices. Problem is, on mobile, the sidebar is not scrollable to see the last item on bottom, and i don't know how to make it look good on mobile screen.

Solution would be something like:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

but this isn't working and idk why. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this inside your "nav" tag

```
height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
```

It's because you working with pixels. It's better for responsive sites to work with a percentage number. Also, try to search for "overflow" propriety

Answer (score 2):

The elements of you nav bar have heights, padding, border, margin.. in px or em.
They add up and overflow your `height: 100vh`.
The easiest solution is like Bob Farias suggested to add `overflow-y: auto` or `overflow-y: scroll` to

```
#sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
  }
```

There are more laborious way to avoid scrolling and overflowing whom would be for example setting your elements "heights" to be fractions of 100vh, or redesigning your nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on mobile browsers such as Safari or Chrome, the browser's toolbar isn't taken into consideration. You can check out a more detail answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser).

A solution to this problem can be found [here](https://ilxanlar.medium.com/you-shouldnt-rely-on-css-100vh-and-here-s-why-1b4721e74487).