# How to detect the if iOS browser's address bar is shown/hidden?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari

I have tried looking for solutions on Stackoverflow, but unfortunately they are all obsolete. I am looking for a device independent way that serve mainly Safari and Chrome.

Comment: It's not easy, but you can write your app based on the view height(css: `vh`) and may be use a js function to update the vh, when size is changed.

Comment: I don't recommend base your app on the view height by using 100vh since sometimes that can lead to weird behaviours. I've had that problem. Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser