# Tailwind h-screen doesn’t work properly on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

The `h-screen` class which should set the height as the height of the screen doesn’t work on iOS. Is there a way to fix that ?

Comment: But what browser on iOS? What version of system, what device? Also it would be good idea to provide some fiddle to tests

Comment: @chojnicki I noticed it on my iPad Pro and iPhone both on safari with the latest iOS/iPadOS. But it appears to affect all mobile devices, check my answer :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Faced the same problem, and found out that we could use dvh (dynamic viewport height).

`h-[calc(100dvh)]` instead of `h-screen`.

However, it's better to add a fallback, just in case.

Comment: That is the answer!

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking to do here. Agree with Bohne, that's that correct answer. The upvoted answer with that absolute weird wrapper container is just a hack.

Answer (score 35):

Often i find useful to set a absolute wrapper outside the content with a `.inset-0` class

```
<!-- this will use the whole viewport even in mobile -->
<div class="absolute inset-0">
    <div>
      lorem ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This fixed my issue with `h-screen` where content was extending below the navigation bar in Samsung Internet on Android. Now it only fills the space visible above the navbar :)

Comment: This worked just fine. Chrome, iOS!

Comment: You are a lifesaver bro goodjob.

Comment: You have no idea how happy I am! All the other solutions I've seen involved confusing javascript and media queries. Thanks!

Comment: This solution has some very weird side effects because it requires the dev to make the position of the element absolute. So no, this is not a very good solution I don't think, and I would avoid using it unless you know every potential side-effect that might occur by using it (in addition to every potential side-effect that might occur as code gets added and the apps scales up)


As terrible as it sounds, you're probably going to avoid trouble in the long run by avoiding the use of absolutely positioned elements and instead setting the height using javascript instead of css.

Comment: Hi @JohnMiller
Absolute elements could have a relative child and it will negate all the sideeffects that you name.

Comment: @NEOJPK No, it won't. Also, I think you mean relative parent, not relative child.

Comment: here @JohnMiller learn something https://play.tailwindcss.com/umHIAf59aA
pd: if im saying relative child its because i know what im talking about you dont get to correct me. Bye

Comment: Either this doesn't work, or I am doing something wrong. What I did was basically wrap my content with the div shown.

Answer (score 8):

Run this JavaScript code on your app load

`document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--vh", window.innerHeight * 0.01 + 'px');`

and put this on your global styles to overwrite h-screen class

```
.h-screen {
    height: 100vh; /* Fallback for browsers that do not support Custom Properties */
    height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh) * 100);
}
```

Comment: This should work however the question is asking about tailwind.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `h-screen` uses `100vh` as the height. As it’s mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser), 100vh aims to not work on mobile devices.

But there is a way to tricks it, but it won’t be added to tailwind because it needs JS. To know more about this ‘trick’ check this article : [The trick to viewport units on mobile](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/)

Answer (score 2):

Adding `h-[100svh]` and `h-screen` as a fallback has solved my issue on iphones

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to my css has proved to be a good solution:

```
@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
  .h-screen {
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main 'div' will take up the full height of the screen, while the inner 'div' will take up the available space, taking into account the height of the browser's navigation bar.

```html
<div class="h-[100vh]">
    <div class="h-[100svh]">
      Bessie the cow
    </div>
</div>
```