# How to get visible height of mobile iphone display

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, height

It looks like the visible display of a iphone 6 is 559px in safari. The address bar and bottom tool bar taking up some real estate.  How do you get the visible height (559px) using javascript or jquery?

run the snippet and inspect with developer for iphone 6,7,and 8

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
        <title>space</title>
        <style>
        body{
            margin:0;
            height:100%;
            position:fixed;
            top:0px;
        }
        
        div{
            height:110px;
            width:100%;
            position:fixed;
            background-color:blue;
        }
        
        #a1{
            top:0px;
            background-color:lightgreen
            }
         #a2{
            top:110px;
            
        }
         #a3{
            top:220px;
            background-color:green;
        }
         #a0{
           top:330px;
            height:7px;
        }
         #a4{
           top:337px;
            background-color:green;
        }
         #a5{
          top:447px;
        }
         #a6{
           top:557px;
            background-color:green;
        }
        
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id='a1' onclick="myFunction()">110</div>
        <div id='a2'>220</div>
        <div id='a3'>330</div>
        <div id='a0'>337</div>
        <div id='a4'>447</div>
        <div id='a5'>557</div>
        <div id='a6'>667</div>
        
        <script>
        function myFunction(){
            var h = window.innerHeight;
            console.log(h);
            
         }   
            
            
        </script>
        
        
        
    </body>
    
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure you can.

Comment: There's an [open bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141832) about this since 2015.

Comment: Use CSS media query.

Comment: @Devang how would using media query help? How do I get the visible height of the device?

Comment: @msg is there a hack or work around?

Comment: There are some solutions and links in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218). Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

window.innerHeight should give the visible height of the screen.

Comment: Did you bother to look at code supplied in the question?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).