# CSS body/height - How to compensate for address bar in mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, css

I'm slightly reluctant to ask as there are a lot of SO answers/posts/articles that supposedly cover this, however after many hours attempting numerous solutions I've been unable to get this working.

The issue is that on a mobile browser, specifically android on a Samsung Galaxy S7 - there is no way to compensate for the address bar, which means if I have full height elements they are cut off at the bottom, or fixed vertically centered elements, they are actually offset and not centered ( when the address bar is showing ).

Some of the solutions I've tried include:

Various javascript/jQuery measurements..

```
window.innerHeight
$(window).height()
etc...
```

None of which update when scrolling and thus hiding the address bar.

Some CSS such as..

```
min-height: -webkit-fill-available !important;
```

Posted solutions such as

https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

[CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)

And also playing around with the viewport meta tag..

Regardless of what I try, the height does not update and the CSS values are specific only to the viewport **without** the address bar which throws off my layout.

Any help would be massively appreciated!