# How can I determine the actual viewport / window height in mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

On my computer / PC it is easy, I simply do:

```
div{
  height: 100vh;
}
```

to create a div that is the height of the window.

However on mobile browsers the height will actually be more than the view port or window.

This causes the div to be scrollable which I do not want.

I see this on both Chrome mobile and Safari mobile

Answer (score 1):

There's no a css solution. Why, you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser). If you want to get 100% of actual viewport on load, you can use javascript to read the height on page load, by calling `window.innerHeight`.

Comment: I heard you were also dope on the mic.  About 5 lines of code and booyaaahhhh it works!