# Div with sticky position relative to the bottom jumps around when scrolling

Tags: css

This is something that I observe on Chrome on mobile (Android). If I have a div with that's using `sticky` for the `position` property and is positioned relative to the bottom, the div will be properly aligned when the page is first loaded, but when scrolling the page so that the browser's navigation bar gets hidden, then the div will jump up and no longer be aligned to the bottom.

Here's an example, using this div

```html
<div style="background-color: red; position: sticky; bottom: 0">Hello world!</div>
```

[image: Before scrolling]
[image: After scrolling]

I suspect the position is not being recalculated once the viewport gets resized. Is this a bug or is this the intended behavior? What's a good way to trigger the repositioning of the div (ideally without JS)?

Comment: If you want the div to stay aligned at the top, you would use sticky positioning, but for the bottom, it is `position: fixed`.

Comment: @MaxVoisard Well, `fixed` doesn't have this issue, but the behavior is different for fixed as it doesn't get unstickied when you scroll past it and it's space doesn't get reserved.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I read through your question too fast. This link might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72830064/sticky-html-element-gets-hidden-below-the-mobile-navigation-bar-in-chrome-fire

Comment: Hi @HansLehnert, were you able to solve the above issue? I'm seeing the same behaviour in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: @iacoware I wasn't able to find a solution without JS, but I posted what I'm currently using below

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find a solution without JS, so this is roughly what I'm currently using.

Inside the div that I want to sticky to the bottom, I added a div with fixed position and transparent color

```html
<div id="hiddenDiv" style="position: fixed; color: transparent;"></div>
```

And then add some code to change the contents on a resize event

```js
var repositionKey = false;

function onResize() {
  repositionKey = !repositionKey;
  document.getElementById("hiddenDiv").innerHTML = repositionKey;
}

addEventListener("resize", onResize);
```

This seems to trigger the position recalculation for the parent element and keeps the sticky div in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

If you add any fixed-position element to the page, the bug with the sticky position element just goes away.

The fixed-position element somehow triggers some form of tracking that probably ought to be triggered by sticky-positioned elements, too - so just by adding an empty element with `position: fixed` the problem is solved.

```
<div style="position: fixed;"/>
```

Comment: Nice find! Doesn't work on Firefox, sadly

Comment: Doesn't work on Chrome either!

Comment: @DATEx2 definitely works on Chrome

Comment: Also works for mobile Samsung browser (tested on Version 23.0.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem in mobile chrome with block which have `posotion:sticky; bottom:0`, it always jumping, but i find this solution on
https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/

```
// We listen to the resize event
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // We execute the same script as before
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});
```