# How to position bottom of an element relative to browser buttons panel on Mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, mobile

The floating button in the website is hidden behind the browser buttons panel. Is there a way to position the element with respect to the browser's buttons panel on Mobile devices?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzn84.gif)

I tried adding `env(safe-area-inset-bottom)` as suggester [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72891733/23175171). I also tried adding `position: static` to `body` as suggested in the same thread. I also tried various other solutions from google and StackOverflow but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved by using `dvh` -> dynamic viewport height.

Old CSS

```css
.floating {
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

Fixed with following

```css
.floating {
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: calc(100dvh - 90px);
}
```