# How to vertically center content below navbar?

Tags: html, css

I want to center the section block vertically with the remainder of the available vertical space on the screen. It should be 100vh - (height of navbar), but I don't know how to achieve that in css

I'm currently setting section height: 100vh but this causes the scrollbar to appear

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 border: 1px solid red
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<nav>
  <div>
    <a>link 1</a>
    <a>link 2</a>
    <a>link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a>download</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
 <h1>This is Centered Vertically</h1>
 <div>
    <h3>However height: 100vh causes a scrollbar to appear</h3>
 </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using flex and `flex:1` solves the problem without using `calc()` (works with dynamic sized navbar).

(**NOTE**: using `100vh` is not recommended since it ignores mobile navigation bars, so in mobile browsers like safari the content will remain scrollable. using 100% on `body` and `html` makes it "real" `100%` height. see : [CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser))

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;

}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 border: 1px solid red
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<nav>
  <div>
    <a>link 1</a>
    <a>link 2</a>
    <a>link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a>download</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
 <h1>This is Centered Vertically</h1>
 <div>
    <h3>However height: 100vh causes a scrollbar to appear</h3>
 </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Kameron `calc` wont work for dynamic height navbar

Comment: @Kameron even OP's navbar is not static in some way. for example accessibility services can increase the font size and make it bigger, your assumption that's the navbar height is 26 is wrong, it depends on more criterions (number of lines etc.).

Comment: Valid arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can either hardcode the height of your navbar into CSS using `calc`:

```css
/* replace 30px with whatever height your navbar has */
height: calc(100vh - 30px);
```

Or you can just apply the height of 100vh to the parent elemnt (in your case the `body`) and let flexbox handle the size of your content container.

Keep in mind that the scrollbar will still appear when the content of the `<section>` is bigger than your screen. If you want to scroll inside the `section`, you will have to add `overflow: auto; and min-height: 0;` to it.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
 flex: none;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 border: 1px solid red
}

section {
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<nav>
  <div>
    <a>link 1</a>
    <a>link 2</a>
    <a>link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div>
   <a>download</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
 <h1>This is Centered Vertically</h1>
 <div>
    <h3>However height: 100vh causes a scrollbar to appear</h3>
 </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved with calc in css but you have to set some height to the navbar e.g.

```
nav {
 height: 80px; // or 10%
}

section {
 height: calc(100vh - 80px); // or calc(100vh - 10%) 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the body to 100% height, make it a flex column and apply `flex:1` to the `section`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <a>link 1</a>
    <a>link 2</a>
    <a>link 3</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>download</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
  <h1>This is Centered Vertically</h1>
  <div>
    <h3>However flex:1 does not cause a scrollbar to appear</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

View in full screen for proper viewing.