# Space under <body> or more exactly under <html>

Tags: html, css, sass

When I access "Responsive Mode" in any browser and I choose and iPad, one of my pages's footer is not at the end of the page.
This happens only on this page because it doesn't have a lot of content to scroll through.

[Whitespace under html/body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zth73.png)

Is this just a Device Toolbar problem? Both in Firefox/Chrome I have this problem

I tried:

`html { height:100% } body {min-height:100% }`

Comment: Can you add the link to the page?

Comment: more information would be useful. so a link to the page as Dream suggests, or some blocks of relevant code.

Comment: Are you using flex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using flex. In a css file,

```
html, body {position: relative; min-height: 100%; height: 100%;}
body {display: flex; flex-flow: column;}

.spring {flex: 1;}
```

In a html file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content elements up here -->
        ...

        <div class="spring"></div>
        <!-- footer or bottom page elements here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The div with the spring class will (should?) push any elements beneath it to the page bottom. If the content exceeds the page or view height, the scroll bar will appear. The spring div should be nested within the body element.

Comment: This indeed worked! I still have some weird margin and I don't know why,(https://imgur.com/a/lXfosRK)  compared with the other pages, but at least is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

good use case for absolute positioning

```css
body{
  min-height:100vh;
  position:relative;
  }
  footer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  }
  
  html,body{
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div>some text</div>
  <footer>my footer</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This ruins more other pages. The footer now covers some content. https://imgur.com/a/10aBfT3

Answer (score 0):

/* Try this to add in top and add your css*/

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

*,*:before,*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit
}

html {
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Does not work ..