# How to set sticky footer in react js using % instead of vh

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My aim is to use % instead of Vh when im dealing with sticky footer in react js.
I tried to use % but the footer won't stick to the bottom.
I set up a simple react app to test this so if anyone knows how to fix it please help me.

Please notice i don't want to apply vh so it can also be mobile friendly at the same time and avoiding fixed heights such as vh.

```
    /*My code */

    **APP js **/

     /*Import Styles*/
     import "./styles/App.scss";
     import "./styles/Variables.scss";
     /*Import the components*/
     import Navigation from "./components/Navigation/Navigation";
     import Showcase from "./components/Showcase/Showcase";
     import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
     /*Components*/
     const App = () => {
        return (
            <div className="App">
              <Navigation />
              <Showcase />
              <Footer />
          </div>
         )
         }
      export  default  App;

       /**App scss **/

      html {
         height: 100%;
         background-color: gray;
       }

      .App {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          min-height: 100%;
        }


       /*Footer scss**/

        .footer {
          min-height: auto;
          border: 1px solid black;
         }


         /**showcase scss **/
        is Empty not styles applied.
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS3 100vh not constant in mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After practice and practice i found a way to do it without using VH

```
/*Import Styles*/
import "./styles/App.scss";
import "./styles/Variables.scss";
/*Import the components*/
import Navigation from "./components/Navigation/Navigation";
import Showcase from "./components/Showcase/Showcase";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
/*Components*/
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navigation />
      <Showcase />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

//Scss App

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}
html,
body,
#root {
  height: 100%;
}
.App {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

// Footer scss

```
.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

This will create sticky footer in react without setting the VH height.

Answer (score 0):

should work when wrapping all content inside a div like in App.js:

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    html {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: gray;
    }
    body, .app {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 100%;
    }
    header {
      height: 50px;
      background-color: lightblue;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    main {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    footer {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: lightgray;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="app">
<header>Sticky Footer Test</header>

<main>content</main>

<footer>Footer Content</footer>

</div>
```

Comment: The thing is I don't want to use position fixed and fixed heights

Comment: @joey edited...

Answer (score -1):

I can't test your code but try: `.footer { margin-top: auto; }`

Or give Showcase a `flex-grow: 1;`.