# position:fixed element just not staying fixed

Tags: css, fixed

I have a weird problem with a div not staying fixed.

I have this fixed box which works like intended in desktop view:

[image]

In mobile view I want this box to act as a bottom menu bar and it does work in general:
[image]

But whenever I scroll down, the box does not stay fixed:
[image]

I have no idea why this happens. The css for this box is:

```
    .scrollnav {
        min-height:100vh;
        height: 100vh;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom: 0;
        top:7vh !important;
        transform: translateY(0);
        padding:0;
        position: fixed;
        margin:0;
        width:100vw;
        font-size:16px;
        z-index:9999;
        pointer-events: none;
        display: block;
        justify-content: center;
        padding-left:2vw;
        align-items: bottom;
    }

    .dots {
        width:95vw;
        left:2vw;
        bottom:0;
        margin-top:-3vh;
        height:11vh;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        padding-top:2vh;
        pointer-events:all;
    }
```

In the html structure it is in last position and only parents are body and html:

```
        <div class="scrollnav">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="active"><a href="#one">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Experience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#three">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#four">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#five">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
html, body {
    all: unset;
    block-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Barlow';
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    scroll-snap-type: both mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
    background: var(--dark);
}
```

I have no idea what is going on here. If you want to take a look at the full code, its online here:

https://b4tt3r.de/neuneu/index.html

I went through all kinds of tips how to make it fixed.

z-index, needs a width and a height, needs position:fixed;, tried position:absolute; as well...

Tried to disable all scripts etc, no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the viewport `<meta>` tag under <head>, adding `minimum-scale=1.0` works on my mobile on Google Chrome.

It seems like in your website some of the components’ width is over 100vw, which somehow causes this problem.

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,
          width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
          minimum-scale=1.0">
<head>
```

In addition, you can try to remove `Top:7vh` and `translateY`, and just use `bottom:0` (or what ever distance you prefer). If both Top and Height are specified, bottom will be ignored. Also, translate() doesn't work well with `position:fixed` since it will translate the position **after** the position is fixed, which might cause problem.

Comment: This solves the problem in developer mode in my desktop chrome, but on my phone it still moves, but now is floating outside the browser box in the bottom.

Comment: Maybe try removing the `transformY` and `Top: 7vh`, to have `bottom: 0` do the work? If both height and Top are specified, `bottom` will be ignored. Also, after this change you probably wouldn't need the `height: 100%`.

Comment: Seems this is the reason for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113430/1794323

Changing the parent box from 100vh to 100% fixed it.