# tailwind css height screen in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have an app that is full screen

```html
<div class="h-screen flex flex-col">
    <div>
        Header
    </div>
    <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
        Main
    </div>
    <div>
        Footer
    </div>
</div>
```

This works normally

[image]

In the phone browser, the bottom menu goes out of the page.
But it works in full screen mode.

[image]

And I could not solve it.
Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr: change `h-screen` to `h-[100dvh]`**

*Update:*

I was scrolling through YouTube and Kevin Powell happened to release a [video about these units](https://youtu.be/ru3U8MHbFFI?si=H-3namBXrMNIcfhA) just a day after my original answer. He does a good job at explaining these dynamic units and some of the resons why you'd want to use one over the other. I'd suggest giving it a watch.

*Original:*

This is beacuse of the way mobile browsers handle the `vh` unit. You can read more about it in [this Stack Overflow answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113430/20913924).

While the answer I shared suggests using Javascript to set the height, there is a relatively new css unit called [`dvh`](https://dev.to/frehner/css-vh-dvh-lvh-svh-and-vw-units-27k4#dynamic-viewport-units). It works like `vh`, but it takes into account the url bar that shows/hides on mobile browsers when you scroll. It's  [current support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_types_length_viewport_percentage_units_dynamic) is promising.

Simply changing the `h-screen` to `h-[100dvh]` should solve your issue.

[This is also a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72245072/20913924) to reference when if you want to learn more about `dvh` and the other dynamic units.

Answer (score 0):

bro you just need to use `h-[100dvh]` for full screen size