# 100lvh not constant in Instagram browser (with bottom and top nav bar)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, instagram

I have a responsive website that works well with all browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) and mobile. But on Instagram browser it seem doesn't work when i scroll (navbar top and bottom appear and disappear when i scroll and change the size of my global flex container (i have fix that on safari mobile version with height:100lvh but no effect on Instagram browser...).

**Example:**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

// Flex container global
const GlobalContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100lvh !important;
`

const IntroComponent = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

    return (<GlobalContainer ref={ref}> 


        </GlobalContainer>);
});

export default IntroComponent
```

I expect to fix this "bug" on instagram browser and keep constant size of flex containers when i scroll.

EDIT : Finally I was able to fix the size with `px` just for Instagram browser with:

```
const isInstagramBrowser = /instagram/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

Comment: Try add height: ${isInstagramBrowser ? 'your_specific_height_px' : '100lvh'} !important;
in to your const GlobalContainer.

Comment: `100vh` isn't a reliable way to get a full screen. See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser